# Are different mexHttpBinding for different endpoints possible in WCF?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, servicecontract

I have 3 service contract interfaces in my WCF library like this:

```
public interface ServiceContract1{}
public interface ServiceContract2{}
public interface ServiceContract3 : ServiceContract1, ServiceContract2 {}
```

Also I have a service which implements ServiceContract3. I can have different endpoints by setting different contracts for each like this:

```
<endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:5556/ServiceContract1"
binding="netTcpBinding" name="netTcpBinding1"
contract="WcfServiceLibrary.IServiceContract1">

<endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:5556/ServiceContract2"
binding="netTcpBinding" name="netTcpBinding2"
contract="WcfServiceLibrary.IServiceContract2">
```

These endpoints seem to work very well but there is only one `mexHttpBinding` endpoint automatically generated. Thus, although a client needs to use one of the endpoints, it will have whole classes after adding Service Reference.

Can i have different `mexHttpBinding` endpoints for different contracts? Is there any approach can i follow? Thanks for your help.

**Edit #1: ServiceModel configuration**

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="WcfServiceLibrary.Service">
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:5556/Service1"
                binding="netTcpBinding" name="netTcpBinding"
                contract="WcfServiceLibrary.IServiceContract1">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:5556/Service2"
                binding="netTcpBinding" name="netTcpBinding"
                contract="WcfServiceLibrary.IServiceContract2">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"
                name="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:5555/ConsoleHost" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I have only one service hosted in my console application:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfServiceLibrary.Service));
host.Faulted += new EventHandler(Host_Faulted);
// Start listening for messages
host.Open();
```

Comment: Can you also show your `<system.serviceModel><services>` configuration? I don't have a very *technical* reasoning, but in practice I have used WCF services exposing 2 services, with different endpoints and metadata exchanges. I manually written those configuration, althought, and I'm not sure my approach is a standard.

Comment: @CoralDoe Added the configuration.